# Bluetooth mouse produces characters while scrolling in 12.04/14.10/15.10

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I have a Logitech bluetooth T630 Ultrathin Optical Touch Mouse and the mouse works as expected most of the time (pairs without problems). However, often (not always) while scrolling, the mouse produces characters (e.g. number 5) repeatedly just as if the key was pressed on the keyboard. This happened both on Ubuntu 12.04, 14.10 and now on 15.10.

This is an excerpt from xev illustrating what happens:

```
ButtonPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 57208, (367,339), root:(1652,369),
    state 0x0, button 4, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 57208, (367,339), root:(1652,369),
    state 0x800, button 4, same_screen YES

ButtonPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 57276, (367,339), root:(1652,369),
    state 0x0, button 4, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 57276, (367,339), root:(1652,369),
    state 0x800, button 4, same_screen YES

KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 57467, (367,339), root:(1652,369),
    state 0x0, keycode 14 (keysym 0x35, 5), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (35) "5"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (35) "5"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 57479, (367,339), root:(1652,369),
    state 0x0, keycode 14 (keysym 0x35, 5), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (35) "5"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

ButtonPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 57490, (367,339), root:(1652,369),
    state 0x0, button 5, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 57490, (367,339), root:(1652,369),
    state 0x1000, button 5, same_screen YES

ButtonPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 57512, (367,339), root:(1652,369),
    state 0x0, button 5, same_screen YES

ButtonRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x9d, subw 0x0, time 57512, (367,339), root:(1652,369),
    state 0x1000, button 5, same_screen YES
```

Any ideas on how to debug this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. Usually it's useable in spite of that but sometimes it produces others that are more interfering like CTRL or ESC. No ideas where to look though... I hope someone else can shed some light.

Comment: Btw. which mouse caused trouble for you? Was it also the Logitech Ultrathin?

Comment: Yeah, same model as yours.